# search function not working - Android

Tags: android, mysql

I am developing a search function (which searches a table in MySQL database) but it is not working. Whenever I type a value in the search bar, toast shows "searching then no results display. I have the main activity where setOnQueryTextListener exists.

```
public class FindSkill extends AppCompatActivity {

    SearchView searchView;
    ListView listView;
    ImageView noData, noNetwork;
    String urlAdress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.find_skill);


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.searchList);
        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        noData = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nodata);
        noNetwork = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nonetwork);
        urlAdress = "http://skillsexchangecyprus.com/SEC/ss.php";



      searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                SenderReceiver sr = new SenderReceiver(FindSkill.this, urlAdress,listView, query,noData,noNetwork);
                sr.execute();
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                SenderReceiver sr = new SenderReceiver(FindSkill.this, urlAdress, listView, query, noData, noNetwork);
                sr.execute();
                return false;
            }});}
}
```

and here is the code of SenderReceiver:

```
public class SenderReceiver extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

    Context ctx;
    String urlAdress;
    String query;
    ListView listView;
    ImageView noData, noNetwork;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;



    public SenderReceiver(Context ctx, String urlAdress, ListView listView, String query, ImageView... imageViews){
        this.ctx=ctx;
        this.urlAdress=urlAdress;
        this.listView=listView;
        this.query=query;
        this.noData=imageViews[0];
        this.noNetwork=imageViews[1];
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Search");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Searching... Please Wait!");
        progressDialog.show();
    }



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return this.sendAndReceive();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        //Reset listView
        listView.setAdapter(null);

        if ( s!= null ){

            if(! s.contains("null")) {
                if(s.length() > 0){
                    Parser parser = new Parser(ctx,s,listView);
                    parser.execute();
                }
            }else {
                noNetwork.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                noData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } //data = "[{\"post_title\":\"title1\"},{\"post_title\":\"title2\"}]";

        }else {
            noNetwork.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            noData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }

    private String sendAndReceive(){

        HttpURLConnection connection = Connector.connection(urlAdress);


        if (connection == null){
            return null;
        }

        try {
            String urlParameters = "query=art";
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.write(urlParameters);
            outputStream.flush();
           // OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter((outputStream));// write it to the network
            bufferedWriter.write(new DataBackager(query).packageData());
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            //response
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            //decode
            if (responseCode == connection.HTTP_OK){
                //return data
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                //read data
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(( new InputStreamReader(inputStream)));
                String line;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                if (bufferedReader != null){
                    while ((line= bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        response.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                }else {
                    return null;
                }

                return response.toString();

            }else{
                return  String.valueOf(responseCode);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

What the log shows when typing in the search bar:

```
03-22 20:19:10.881 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{8d1f108 V.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
03-22 20:19:10.891 27300-28889/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-22 20:19:10.891 27300-28889/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-22 20:19:10.891 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
03-22 20:19:10.941 27300-27456/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1592x909]-format:1
03-22 20:19:10.961 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
03-22 20:19:10.991 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
03-22 20:19:11.671 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
03-22 20:19:11.701 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
03-22 20:19:15.261 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{89ca702 V.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
03-22 20:19:15.271 27300-28989/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-22 20:19:15.271 27300-28989/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-22 20:19:15.281 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
03-22 20:19:15.331 27300-27456/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1592x909]-format:1
03-22 20:19:15.341 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
03-22 20:19:15.351 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
03-22 20:19:15.451 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
03-22 20:19:15.481 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
03-22 20:19:15.991 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
03-22 20:19:16.031 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
03-22 20:19:16.151 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1128) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1128) or=1
03-22 20:19:16.161 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
03-22 20:19:45.241 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.431 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.531 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.531 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.531 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.671 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.691 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{77cc7ba token=android.os.BinderProxy@39d6639 {com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange.FindSkill}} show : true
03-22 20:19:45.691 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.701 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.701 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.711 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:45.711 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
03-22 20:19:46.101 27300-27300/com.example.joudialfattal.skillsexchange D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
```

Pasrer class code:

```
public class Parser extends AsyncTask <Void, Void,Integer> {

    Context ctx;
    ListView listView;
    String data;
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();


    public Parser(Context ctx, String data, ListView listView) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.data=data;
        this.listView = listView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return this.parse();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);

        if (integer == 1) {
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Unable to Parse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    private int parse() {


        try {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);
            JSONObject jo = null;

            titles.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = jo.getString("post_title");
                titles.add(title);
            }
            return 1;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

PS: PHP code is 100% working because I tried it with the database and it showed the desired results.

Comment: Do you have the expected answer at : response.toString() ?

Comment: yes this's the case.

Comment: And what is the value of 's' in protected void onPostExecute(String s) ? Still the expected return value?

Comment: you mean instead of s it should be response?

Comment: Nope I am asking the value of that 's' variable. Did you make sure it is still the value return by your php server ?

Comment: No I didn't. I followed a tutorial that suggested the code. How can I make sure that about the value of s?

Comment: I guess you know how to debug. Right?

Comment: How did you that response.toString() was the expected answer you were expecting at the first place?

Comment: I thought it should be because it is the StringBuffer object

Comment: What you mean by StringBuffer and how did you checked that ?

Comment: Sorry my bad I was wrong. response has nothing to do with the result from the server. It is only an variable that holds the status of the connection. The result from the server is held in 's'.

Comment: Okay. Now, what is your goal doing this ' listView.setAdapter(null);' ?

Comment: for example if a particular search doesn't have any result, but in the previous query there was some data, so noData image will be shown on top of the listview with the previous data. --> clearing the list.

Comment: This is not really the right way... Also, how do you populate your listview when you get the result from the server currently ?

Comment: You do not have an arrayAdapter. I will suggest you to check this link to understand how listviews work first. http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/populating-listview-with-arraylist.html

Regards,

Comment: I do have an adapter it is within the Parse class which sets the adapter for the list.

Comment: I do not see any Parse class above

Comment: @user3793589 this part creates an instance of Parse class + I added the code of Parse class in the post
if(! s.contains("null")) {
                if(s.length() > 0){
                    Parser parser = new Parser(ctx,s,listView);
                    parser.execute();
                }

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
urlAdress = "http://skillsexchangecyprus.com/SEC/ss.php";
```

to

```
urlAdress = "https://skillsexchangecyprus.com/SEC/ss.php";
```